# create_session': no sessionId in returned payload (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

My Ruby environment was working sometime ago, but it broke so I'm trying to set it up again. I'm following these instructions. https://www.agiletrailblazers.com/blog/the-5-step-guide-for-selenium-cucumber-and-gherkin

I installed Ruby2.33 and extracted the dev kit to the same folder. I ran these installs with no problem. They all said gems were installed successfully

```
ruby dk.rb init

ruby dk.rb install

gem install bundler

gem install selenium-webdriver -v 3.2.1

gem install cucumber

gem install rspec
```

I create a .rb file in a separate folder and running the script is supposed to open firefox, navigate to the website and close the browser. All it does is open a blank firefox browser and it doesn't close.

My script is

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox

driver.navigate.to "http://mock.agiletrailblazers.com/"

driver.quit
```

I'm getting the below error
[image]

I also tried gem install webdrivers. My firefox install is inside my program files as well.

Anyone know why I can't run my script after all these commands and installs worked fine?

Comment: Are you using Firefox > 47 version? If yes, you need to download geckodriver and keep it in path.

Comment: You're saying that if I have a version greater than 47, I need to download geckodriver and keep it in path?

Comment: So before, I guess I didn't fully understand what add to path meant. I thought it meant adding my drivers folder to the same folder as my ruby install. Then I thought it meant I had to add it as an environment variable. Then I figured out that I needed to add it to the path in my system variables. Anyway it worked. Thanks. I'll be back when I run into my next error.